# Command-line cURL submit form from other files

Tags: curl

In this command:

```
curl -d param1=value1 -d param2=value2 http://example.com/submit
```

If `value1` is located in `file1.txt`, how can I make cURL include `file1.txt` in the command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick: `curl -d param="$(cat file1.txt)" ...`

Comment: You can also do `$(< file1.txt)` and avoid using `cat`.

Comment: Right.  I just love cats :)

Comment: You can do '--data-urlencode' option with 'param@file1.txt' semantic :).