# How can I give an argument as an external file to curl with url encode?

Tags: curl

I try to request query.wikidata.org using curl.

The following command line works perfectly :

```
$ curl -G https://query.wikidata.org/bigdata/namespace/wdq/sparql --data-urlencode query='PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX p: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/>
PREFIX ps: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/>
PREFIX pq: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/qualifier/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?item ?itemLabel
WHERE {
?item wdt:P31 wd:Q146 . 
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}' -H 'Accept: text/csv'
```

Since the SPARQL part of the query is long and complex, I would like to store it in an external file (say cats.sparql) and call the file in the curl command line.

This would be cats.sparql :

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX p: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/>
PREFIX ps: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/>
PREFIX pq: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/qualifier/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel
WHERE {
?item wdt:P31 wd:Q146 .
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
```

Now, the following command line returns an error :

```
 $ curl -G https://query.wikidata.org/bigdata/namespace/wdq/sparql --data-urlencode query=cats.sparql -H 'Accept: text/csv'curl -G https://query.wikidata.org/bigdata/namespace/wdq/sparql --data-urlencode query=cats.sparql -H 'Accept: text/csv'
```

Here is the beginning of the error :

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openrdf.query.MalformedQueryException: Lexical error at line 1, column 12.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "cats.sparql"
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've finally found a solution on this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17375/command-line-curl-submit-form-from-other-files?rq=1)

```
$ curl -G https://query.wikidata.org/bigdata/namespace/wdq/sparql --data-urlencode query="$(< cats.sparql)" -H 'Accept: text/csv' > wikidata_cats.csv
```